# Intermediate value theorem for two functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-verification, continuity

Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then if $g(a) \leq f(a)$ and $f(b) \leq g(b)$, then it exists an $x \in [a,b]$ so that $f(x) = g(x)$.

What I've got:

First according to the IVT exists an $u \in [f(a),f(b)]$, so that $u = f(x)$ with $x \in [a,b]$. But it also means $u \in (g(a),g(b))$, since $f$ is bounded by $g$. Therefore again according to the IVL, we have $u = g(y)$ with $y \in  [a,b]$. From that follows $$f(x) = u = g(y)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

*From here on I am not sure*

Since $f$ is bounded by $g$ then $f(x) \in (g(a),g(b))$, $ \ (2)$. Lastly, $x,y$ are both from $[a,b]$, $(3)$.

From $(1),\ (2),\ (3)$ follows that $x = y$ and hence $f(x) = g(x)$.

**Question**
Is the proof correct? If not, where am I wrong and how can I get it right?

Comment: Hint: Look at $f(x)-g(x)$.

Comment: It is not assumed that $f$ is bounded by $g$! We only have some information on the values at the extrema of the domain $a$ and $b$. So, your proof doesn't work. In particular there is no reason to believe that $x=y$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [proof Intermediate Value Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2207994/proof-intermediate-value-theorem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ then $h$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ also $h(a)$ and $h(b)$ are of opposite sign, therefore by IVT $h(c)=0$ for $c\in[a,b]$ i.e., $f(c)=g(c).$

Answer (score 2):

A simple proof would be as following(I'm not sure your proof is 100% correct):

Let $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$, which is also continuous. Since $h(a) \geq 0$ and $h(b) \leq 0$, then from the Intermediate value theorem it follows that there is a $x \in [a, b]$ such that $h(x) = 0$, hence $f(x) - g(x) = 0$, $f(x) = g(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have to show equality using IVL defining a new function $h$ is usually a good idea
$h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$
You get $h(a)>0$ and $h(b)<0$ h is a continous function and using IVL there exists and $\epsilon $ in $ [a;b]$ so that $h(\epsilon)=0$

Answer (score 0):

A few problems with your attempt:

Your statement $u\in (g(a),g(b))$, which you repeat as step 2), isn't justified. We only know that the values of $f$ at the endpoints are $\ge$ and $\le$ the values of $g$ at the endpoints, not $>$ and $<$. That is, we only know that $f(x)\in[g(a), g(b)]$, and not that $f(x)$ is in the *open* interval between $g(a), g(b)$.

Step 3) doesn't add anything new either. From what you've established, there's no way to conclude that $x=y$! (unless $a=b$).

---

As all the other answers and some comments have pointed out, the usual trick in such situations is to consider the function $h = f-g$, the difference of $f$ and $g$. The hypothesis says that $h(a)\le 0\le h(b)$, so by the intermediate value theorem, there is an $x\in[a,b]$ such that $h(x) = 0$, which is to say, $f(x) = g(x)$.